# warning : the scripts ........ are installed in somewhere which is not on path

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to write an AI program in python using jupyter and I have anaconda installed on my windows computer. and now I'm trying to install the jupyterlab by writing "pip install jupyterlab" in cmd. but then it gives me a warning that: 
"The scripts jupyter-migrate.exe, jupyter-troubleshoot.exe and jupyter.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\AA\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location."

I want to know how to add all of these scripts to PATH.
can I just copy and paste all of these files from the directory they're installed on to the path in windows environment variables ? or is it a different path I'm looking for?
(I'm using python 3.7 on windows 10).
thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you install that package through anaconda repositories?

```
conda install jupyterlab
```

So you will have those tools in your conda envs. 
You have 2 choices for doing so, the first would be installing it in the  'base' env and you will have access to jupyterlab in every other env you create, otherwise you could install it only in the env where you need it.

Might it be a good workaround?